# install snap nextcloud on best way

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, snap, nextcloud

Standard in Ubuntu 18.04 there is a snap **nextcloud**, one for the server and one for the client. On the internet I see many different ways to install them, especially for the server.

My question is what is the best/safest way to install them, completed with lets encrypt certification?

Comment: Do you have a domain name pointing to your IP ? Otherwise lets encrypt won't work.

Comment: Yes, I have. I have already installed nextcloud and the cliënt. It works. But I wonder if done on the rigt way.

Comment: I have installed it with the use of: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-nextcloud-on-ubuntu-18-04.

Comment: There are a few different ways you can configure the Nextcloud snap. In this guide, rather than creating an administrative user through the web interface, we will create one on the command line in order to avoid a small window where the administrator registration page would be accessible to anyone visiting your server's IP address or domain name.

Comment: To configure Nextcloud with a new administrator account, use the nextcloud.manual-install command. You must pass in a username and a password as arguments. I have it done in the web interface. But I want to change that to do it in the terminal. I have seen also other ways to install: with mariadb, rules for ufw, automatic renew certificates, etc, https://itsyndicate.org/blog/install-letsencrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-ubuntu-18-04/,